# Private variable prints as garbage value when using OpenMP SECTIONS directive

Tags: c, openmp

Inside the parallel block of my code I reference a thread private variable, `tid`. `tid` is assigned in a SECTIONS directive.

However, when I print its value I receive a garbage value inside the parallel block but outside the sections block.

Why do I get a garbage value?

What I know is you usually get a garbage value if you access a variable outside a `omp parallel` block and not being defined as `lastprivate`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

/* 4 threads, 1 core */
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int nthreads, tid;

    /* Fork a team of threads giving them their own copies of variables */
    #pragma omp parallel private(tid) 
    {
        #pragma omp sections
        {
            /* Obtain thread number */
            tid = omp_get_thread_num();

            printf("Hello World from thread = %d\n", tid);

            /* Only master thread does this */
            if (tid == 0) 
            {
                nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
                printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
            }

            printf("Inside sections %d \n" ,tid);
        }

        printf("Out of sections %d  \n", tid );

        #pragma omp single
        {
            printf("Inside single block %d \n" , tid);
        }
    }  /* All threads join master thread and disband */

    printf("Outside parallel block \n");
}
```

Below is the output I received:

```
Hello World from thread = 3
Inside sections 3 
Out of sections 0  
Inside single block 0 
Out of sections 1  
Out of sections 3  
Out of sections -1078056856  
Outside parallel block
```

Why did `tid` give that garbage value (-1078056856)?

Comment: It looks like `tid` might not get initialized, but I'm not all that familiar with OpenMP.

Comment: You haven't declared anything to be an `omp section`. Likely you've found some undefined behavior.

Comment: Do you mean it is not acceptable to write code inside the sections block and not inside section blocks?

Comment: My compiler has the following complaint about your code:

    `error: ‘tid’ may be used uninitialized in this function`

Answer (score 2):

1. You should initialize `tid` before parallel block
2. To use this its value inside threads declare it as `firstprivate(tid)` in the `pragma omp`